# Regression problem where target has Gaussian distribution

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I am trying to build a regression model where the target values from the training dataset have a gaussian-like distribution. When I try different types of models (MLP, RandomForest, etc), they all end up predicting values close to the mean and fail to predict values that are further away from the center of data. My input data is normalized floating-point values with 15 features and with using neural networks I'm using mean squared error as loss function. How should I change my model (or data) so that it learns to predict outliers? I've considered a loss function that adds an extra penalty when the ground-truth value is an outlier but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: This sounds like the general phenomenon known, for approximately a century and a half, as "regression to the mean."  If so, the short answer is you need features that predict the response better!

Comment: I have a suggestion for an experiment to determine if the inputs can predict the extremes of the target values. As a test, separate the highest 10 percent and lowest 10 percent of the target values and regress those. If the test regression cannot tell the difference in these two data groups, adding in the rest of the data will not help to do so.